# Spreading one column to Multiple columns in R (Spread?, Reshape?)

Tags: r, subset, reshape, spread

I want to get rid of the Station.ID column in the table below by distributing (Spread?, Reshape?) it to the month columns so that I get columns such as Jan_323,  Feb_323, ... , Jan_452, Feb_452, ...

```
 Have:

 Station.ID  Year    Jan   Feb    Mar   Apr  May   Jun
 323         1995    31.3  25.2   19.0   15.0 ..    .. 
 323         1996    28.0  20.2   17.5   14.0 ..    ..
 323         ...     ..    ..     ..     ..   ..    ..
 ...         ...     ..    ..     ..     ..   ..    ..
 452         1995    16.2  ..     ..     ..   ..    ..
 452         1996    14.3  ..     ..     ..   ..    ..
 452         ...     ..    ..     ..     ..   ..    ..
 ..          ...     ..    ..     ..     ..

 Want:

 Year    Jan_323  Feb_323   Mar_323  ...  Jan_452   Feb_452   Mar_452   ...
 1995     31.3     25.2     19.0     ...   16.2       ...       ...     ...
 1996     28.0      ...       ...    ...   14.3       ...       ...     ...
 1997     ...       ...       ...    ...   ...        ...       ...     ...    
 1998     ...       ...       ...    ...   ...        ...       ...     ...
 ....     ...       ...       ...    ...   ...        ...       ...     ...
```

Comment: Hi - Can you please include a reproducible data set?  (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We could use `spread` after `gather`ing into 'long' format

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, key, value, -Station.ID, -Year) %>% 
      unite(Station.ID, key, Station.ID) %>% 
      mutate(Station.ID = factor(Station.ID, levels = unique(Station.ID))) %>%
      spread(Station.ID, value)
#   Year Jan_323 Jan_452 Feb_323 Feb_452 Mar_323 Mar_452 Apr_323 Apr_452 May_323 May_452 Jun_323 Jun_452
#1 1995    31.3    16.2    25.2    20.1    19.0    31.2    15.0    12.2    12.0    12.5    10.1    22.1
#2 1996    28.0    14.3    20.2    23.1    17.5    34.2    14.0    14.2    10.5    13.5    12.2    19.1
#3 1997    20.2    20.1    22.1    22.1    31.2    32.2    12.2    13.2    12.5    11.5    22.1    18.1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Station.ID = c(323L, 323L, 323L, 452L, 452L, 452L
), Year = c(1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L), Jan = c(31.3, 
28, 20.2, 16.2, 14.3, 20.1), Feb = c(25.2, 20.2, 22.1, 20.1, 
23.1, 22.1), Mar = c(19, 17.5, 31.2, 31.2, 34.2, 32.2), Apr = c(15, 
14, 12.2, 12.2, 14.2, 13.2), May = c(12, 10.5, 12.5, 12.5, 13.5, 
11.5), Jun = c(10.1, 12.2, 22.1, 22.1, 19.1, 18.1)), .Names = c("Station.ID", 
"Year", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L))
```

Comment: Success! I was hoping for a simpler solution using just spread, but a few more lines of code won't kill me. Thanks!

Comment: The `mutate` line is just to create the columns in an order